# H2 - Alter Sequence Rename

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, sequence, h2

Is there a way to change the name of a sequence-table in H2 (scenario is Postgres and H2 for testing purposes).

For the Postgres following would be feasible:

```
alter sequence student_id_seq rename to pupil_id_seq;
```

For the H2 that does not work since it has cryptical names for the Sequence-Tables. I'd like to prevent, dropping the student-table completely and creating it new.

Thanks in advance, happy coding and have a nice day.

Comment: Unfortunately, H2 does not support rename command for sequences yet. You can only remove all references to the sequence, drop it, create a new one, and restore references to it. Usually you should use identity columns (`GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`) and not use the sequences directly, unless you need to share the sequence between multiple tables for a some reason. Here is the related feature request: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/417

Comment: Agree for that, unfortunately that feature is not available in the used Postgres version 9.6.5